# How to profile an application only when it is stuttering?

Tags: qt, profiling, perf

I have a QT application that I'm trying to increase the performance of. I've gotten it to the point where it runs at nearly 60 fps, but there are still a lot of dropped frames that noticeably decrease smoothness. In a standard call-graph-based profile of CPU usage, whatever is causing those stutters is lost in normal application activity. I want to view a profile of the application for only the times when it is dropping frames. What's the best way to do this?

One idea would be to add code to the application to detect when it is running smoothly, and tell `perf` to drop the last frame's activity, but I don't know how to detect that within QT nor how the application would communicate that to `perf`.